# Is there a way to change the screen resolution?

Tags: resolution, acer, monitor, citrix

I have an Acer Aspire one, with screen resolution of 1024x600. Standard monitor resolution that is closest to this is 1024x768.  Is there a way to "compress" a programs output to the screen (assuming it wants to display on a 1024x768 screen) so that it is viewable on a non standard resolution (1024x600)

The problem I have is that Citrix is trying to use 1024x768 but my screen is 1024x600. This ends up cutting off the bottom 168 pixels at the bottom of the image.  Often this makes the Citrix program unusable since many GUI forms have buttons somewhere in this cutoff area.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no fix AFAIK. But you can usually drag the window keeping ALT pressed, clicking on any place of the window and dragging the mouse. That way you can reach the part of the screen that are hidden. Not exactly a great solution, but useful for occasional use.

Comment: This is the way that I am getting around the problem.  I would still like to have a way to adjust the resolution or compress the "default" size for some applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the Aspire Ones. You need to fix up the resolution settings to give you native resolution equal to your screen's, since the resolution of the screen is not one of the standard ones.

This is for the A0751h (mine) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne/AO751h note that the resolution is different from yours, would help if you gave your model number.

By making it the right monitor resolution, your problem might be resolved. Though some programs do have this problem where they want a specific minimum dimension or you can't use it.

Comment: I have an Acer Aspire One AOA150

Comment: Put that in your post as an edit. Unfortunately its not on the list :( Maybe someone else might have an idea. But yea edit your OP with additional data always.

Answer (score 0):

I know absolutely diddly about Citrix but suggest that you investigate whether you can't configure the window size in the Citrix client...

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be application specific, but there is often a 'fit to screen' option.

You didn't mention what client version you are using, but look for Display -> Session Resolution -> Fit to Screen.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talking about the client.

Have a look at the configfile in ~/.ICAClient/appsrv.ini
Search for the *[yourConnectionName]* entry an put this in:

```
DesiredVRES=600
DesiredHRES=1024
```

You can also use the gui to configure this:

```
/usr/lib/ICAClient/wfcmgr -icaroot /usr/lib/ICAClient
```

*You can find a reference of all settings here: http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/ica-settings/ica-settings-wrapper.html*

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

1. Run `regedit`. regedit can be found in the Windows folder
2. Highlight the highest tree level (Computer)
3. Search for "Display1_DownScalingSupported" and changed it from "0" to "1"
4. Restart the system.
5. Enjoy the two new resolutions: 1024×768 px and 1152×864

Comment: Did you notice this is not askwindows.com?